# Inner left join with linq returns too many results

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, repository-pattern

I have been years since i last have been working with inner joins so i am a bit rusty.
It have 3 tables

Albums, AlbumsImages and User

Now first in my Repository i Inner Left Join Album and AlbumsImages, the thing is i only want the first entery from albumsimages order by firs Cover Desc then Id Desc (There can be 0 images in AlbumImages!). After that do i join with my user table, on the userid in albums to id in user.
My problem is that i do not get only 1 album, but a result for each image in albumsImages, where i only want 1.
What am i doing wrong here?

```
    public IQueryable<Album> Get()
    {
        return (from a in context.Albums
                join i in _imageRepository.Get() on a.Id equals i.AlbumId into albumImages
                from cover in albumImages.DefaultIfEmpty()
                orderby cover.Cover descending, cover.Id ascending 
                select new Album()
                    {
                        Id = a.Id,
                        UserId  = a.UserId,
                        Name  = a.Name,
                        Created  = a.Created,
                        LastEdit  = a.LastEdit,
                        Description  = a.Description,
                        Views  = a.Views,
                        Location  = a.Location,
                        Photoshoot  = a.Photoshoot,
                        Cover = cover,
                    });
    }

var albums = (from a in AlbumRepository.Get()
                            join u in UserRepository.Get() on a.UserId equals u.Id
                            orderby a.Id descending
                            select new AlbumDisplayModel()
                                {
                                    Album = a,
                                    User = u
                                }).ToList();
```

Test:

```
    return (from i in _imageRepository.Get()
            join album in context.Albums on i.AlbumId equals album.Id into albums
            from a in albums.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new Album()
                {
                    Id = a.Id,
                    UserId  = a.UserId,
                    Name  = a.Name,
                    Created  = a.Created,
                    LastEdit  = a.LastEdit,
                    Description  = a.Description,
                    Views  = a.Views,
                    Location  = a.Location,
                    Photoshoot  = a.Photoshoot,
                    Cover = i,
                });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take off `DefaultIfEmpty` from `albumImages`. That's going to return the album image regardless of whether there's a match or not (left join).

Comment: Yes i forgot to add that an album can have 0 images, and i would still like to have the album out in that instance

Comment: @DoomStone Then change your 2nd query to perform an `into` with a `DefaultIfEmpty`

Comment: I don't understand, you wante the user table to join with a into and DefaultIfEmpty? there will always the a user with the given userid!

Comment: @DoomStone Ah apologies, you'd have to rewrite the first query to do `from i in _imageRepository.Get()` then do the join `DefaultIfEmpty` on the album table, that way you'll always get all albums regardless.

Comment: I have tryed to do what you said :D See the "Test" in my OP, it returns the same as the other method though :( @mattytommo